# Set up X window manager on RHEL under WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, window-manager, wsl2

I'm running RHEL 8 under WSL in Windows 10, and want to use X11 GUI.  I can't upgrade to Windows 11, so I can't take advantage of the Win 11 solution to GUI for WSL.

I have set up an X server (vcxsrv, running in "one large window" mode) on Windows and can run apps like xterm and they display as expected.

I can run a window manager like metacity or kwin, and it will decorate the xterm with a title bar etc., but there is no background menu on the X desktop.  I've searched a lot but can't seem to find how to set up a window manager from nothing.  I have used X a lot in the past, and it's always a bit different for every new context, and I don't remember the details.

I installed metacity and kwin using `sudo yum install metacity kwin`.  Hopefully there's a simple way to set up a new basic user enviroment but I can't find the proper incantations.  Everything I find is for setting up Linux with a monitor or some other context that doesn't apply (and usually has things implicitly installed that is not the case for me.)

I tried metacity and kwin because they're supported according to RHEL docs: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/deployment_guide/s2-x-clients-winmanagers .

The man page for metacity says "Metacity configuration can be found under Preferences->Windows (etc) on the menu-panel."  Yes, if there was a menu-panel, but there isn't.

I'd just like a basic setup with a few default apps (like xterm) and that I can tailor to my purposes.  I'd also like multiple virtual screens, one visible at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>The background isn't provided by the window manager; it's provided by the X server. Specifically, the background in X is usually called the "root window", and you're currently running vcxsrv in "rootless" mode – rootless is what most people running X on Windows expect.</del>

<del>I installed VcXsrv and it seems to have an "XLaunch" launcher like Xming, asking you to choose the operating mode. In this dialog, "Multiple windows" enables rootless mode – instead; you want to choose **one of the other three.**</del>

The menu panel is also not provided by the window manager in this case. It is with some window managers (such as GNOME Shell or Enlightenment), but not with Metacity – remember that Metacity was the window manager *for GNOME 2*, in which the panel was a separate app literally called `gnome-panel`. If you have MATE installed for the "traditional GNOME look and feel" it will have `mate-panel`, and similarly Xfce4 has `xfce4-panel`.

Same goes for desktop icons, which are drawn by `xfdesktop4` in Xfce4, by Nautilus in GNOME 2 (aka Caja in MATE), and so on. The equivalent for KDE Plasma is probably the `plasmashell` which handles both the taskbar and the desktop in a unified way. (On the other hand, Enlightenment has it all as a built-in part of the WM.)

Probably the reason you don't "automatically" have panels and icons is because Metacity was *not meant* to be used as a standalone window manager – it was always a component of the GNOME desktop, which would be launched through a "session manager" that knows about all necessary components that need to be started.

That is, normally you would run `mate-session` or `startplasma` or `xfce4-session` and that would launch the window manager, the desktop, the panel, the panel applets, the user-defined custom startup applications, etc. (Another task of the session manager is telling apps to prepare for an imminent logout/shutdown.)

There are window managers more suitable for standalone usage; e.g. Openbox adds a right-click menu to the desktop for launching applications so you can survive without menu panels, although it works nicely with gnome-panel as well. Usually those window managers do have their own "startup" command list and don't use a separate session manager, but it remains up to you to assemble the entire kit.

Comment: As @user1686 points out, x11 simply wasn't designed to work this way (and for this I am thankful).  It is a beautiful design just like it is.  I would suggest that if you want the full screen window manager experience, run a VM.  This would be NO DIFFERENT if you were doing x11 forwarding between Linux boxes.  Good luck! :)

Comment: I wasn't saying it wasn't designed to work this way, but rather that the features were designed to be provided by additional components on top of what OP has installed. (What X11 _wasn't_ designed for is being performant over a network when bitmap-heavy modern apps are being used, unlike more modern bitmap-oriented protocols like RDP or VNC... With WSL's loopback connection that might not be noticeable, though Microsoft did decide to use Wayland-over-RDP rather than X11 for their "WSLg" feature.)

Comment: Fair enough @user1686 :) .. I was using x11 and open windows in the 80s and exporting the whole window manager or desktop environment was never in the cards as far as design goes.  I thought that is what you were eluding to but clearly not.  You clearly know what you are talking about though.. thanks for the post.

Comment: I am exactly trying to work as though this were a headless VM.  And I am using "One large window" model, and I am not passing any `--rootless` option.  I'm surprised that the window manager runs on the client yet the background is owned by the server, but that would explain why I can't find what I'm looking for because I'm barking up the wrong tree.  Thanks!  (It also seems odd that a menu on the server would invoke applications on the client, like running an xterm.)

Comment: I'm still a bit confused.  So, I need to find a program for windows that will provide the desktop?  I'd sure rather stick to Linux for this.  (And now I do remember gnome-panel.)

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: On the contrary, I'm finding several descriptions of MIT using it heavily for its Athena environment (with labs containing X terminals); seems to me like the whole purpose of e.g. `xdm` was to allow this – it even had the XDMCP protocol for X terminals to remotely log in to remote systems.

Comment: @JeffLearman: Do you mean being able to launch xterm through vcxsrv's popup menu? That just runs a *local* xterm.exe client, not one in the VM. No, you do not need to find a Windows program. All programs I've listed are **regular X11 programs** that connect to the X display like xterm does. If you can run Metacity on Linux and have it connect to a VcXsrv display, there's nothing that'd stop you from running gnome-panel on Linux in the exact same way.

Comment: @JeffLearman: Ah, my mistake, you were talking about the background *menu* rather than the background itself. The right-click menu is indeed displayed "remotely" on the X client, in window managers which have it. However, Metacity never had such a menu. (That was Nautilus' job.)

Comment: xfce4-panel solves the issue, thanks.  My confusion stems from the fact that I usually run client and server on the same machine.  (BTW, I once knew a lot about X, as I ported X11 to run over OSI.  But that was in the 90's and I've forgotten all those details.)  Not sure how to install gnome-panel anyway, but xfce was easy enough.  Still no background menu but enough other stuff to survive.

Comment: Any way to set the background?  `xsetroot -solid blue` has no effect.

Comment: If you're running Metacity in compositing mode (usual nowadays), that's another thing I forgot: the background that you *see* is part of the composite overlay window. Try other tools such as `hsetroot` or `feh` which are able to set its background.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131269/discussion-between-jeff-learman-and-user1686).